# Populate cell in TableView from array and save the data in the cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to load an array into the **first only** cell of my TableView, that means that I want the data in a single line. Afterwords I need these data to persist be saved so that they remain after I close and reopen the app.
Here is my TableView class that loads the array's data in each cell though instead only in the first one:

```
import UIKit

class ScoreboardViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    let info = ["\(name01) ", "\(name02) ",  "\(name03) ", "\(name04) ", "\(myCategory) ", "\(displayTime)"]



    @IBOutlet weak var myTv: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
        myTv.delegate = self
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return info.count
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //Allocate a table view cell
        let cell = myTv.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = info[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Since I do not use Core Data in my app, would be better to save everything in a file or use NSUserDefaults?

Comment: check for `if(indexPath.row==0)` to populate only first cell. and use `NSUserDefaults` since it would be a very small data.

Answer (score 0):

You should divide data and visual output of data - so saving data for the app next launch shouldn't be related to `UITableView` at any way - use some nice patters, like `MVVM` or `MVC`. You can use some storage mechanisms like `CoreData`, `NSUserDefaults` as key-value data, SQL-base, output to file and many others.
In you case, i think `NSUserDefaults` is quite enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to store the `Array` then use an `NSArray` and store it using the convenient methods writeToFile and `arrayWithContentsOfFile`.

For limited amount of data you could also abuse the `NSUserDefaults`.

For larger amounts of data (lets say, if you don't know whether the number of rows is anyhow limiete) I strongly suggest to user Core Data for it.